# Download file in android studio with the original file name

Tags: android, download, filenames

How to write the code to download file in android studio with the original file name?

I am trying to create a very simple webview mobile android application as I am a beginner in this field. I am almost done but I am stuck at a problem. It is working perfectly with `.pdf` but it is saving `.lrc` files with `.txt` extension.

My code is:

**MainActivity.java**

````
webview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String fileExtenstion, long contentLength) {

                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
                String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                request.addRequestHeader("cookie",cookies);
                request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent",userAgent);
                request.setDescription("Downloading file....");
                request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url,contentDisposition,fileExtenstion));
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, fileExtenstion));
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Downloading File",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });  ```

**AndroidManiFest.xml**
````

```

Can you guys help me to make it right please.

Comment: Can you check the value of `mimeType` ? Is it the correct one?

Comment: I am newbie, I am trying to figure out your say

Comment: If you have a short url that does nit contain the file name you are out of luck.

Comment: If you want control over the filename, download the content yourself (e.g., using OkHttp), rather than using `DownloadManager`.

Comment: After many attempts I am failed to do that, I tried ''String fileExtenstion = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
String name = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, null, fileExtenstion);''

Comment: I want to know is there any way that a user can set the file name by himself when downloading starts

Comment: Of course. Instead of guess filename put the one you want.

Comment: I solved my issue, I made my download links currect now it's taking the file name from the url, but I am facing now a new issue that is with file extention. it is working perfecetly with .pdf but it is saving **.lrc** files with **.txt** extention.  can you guys rewite the code to solve this problem